# algoliasearch() has no signature call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I was following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/3Z0V3cvgns8). And I have encountered the error below

```
 Type 'typeof import("C:/Users/admin/Documents/project/app/functions/node_modules/algoliasearch/index")' has no call signatures.
```

This is the code

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();
const env = functions.config();

import * as algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch';

const  client = algoliasearch(env.algolia.appid, env.algolia.apikey);
```

And I get it from using the **algoliasearch** function.
Here are the versions of firebase, algoliasearch, and angular

```
"firebase": "^7.5.2"
"algoliasearch": "^4.2.0"
"@angular/cli": "~7.3.8"
```

Comment: For questions or concerns pertaining to Firebase products and services, I would like to direct you to the [Firebase Support page](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact?authuser=0). As they would be better suited in providing answers to your Firebase inquiries.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
import * as algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch'
```

with

```
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch';
```

Reference: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/sending-and-managing-data/send-and-update-your-data/tutorials/firebase-algolia/#create-main-indexjs

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include the most important and relevant information in the link provided in the answer itself. This can help stop your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.